# Regex to get the right most number after $

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have the following string and I am trying to get the right most numbers from them.

Input:

```
-30%$13.99$19.99
$19.99
```

Output:

```
$19.99
$19.99
```

What is the best way for me to do this with regex?

Here is what I have so far:

```
[\$ ]+?(\d+([,\.\d]+)?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
/\$[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/mg
```

```js
/\$\d+(\.\d+)?$/mg
```

Tested with **ECMAScript (JavaScript)** and **PCRE2 (PHP >=7.3)** on the string that you provided

- `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?` stands for float or integer numbers.
- The last `$` stands for the end of the line.